# How to Append Data to existing Yaml

Tags: pyyaml

Here is my YAML:

```
---
version: 1.0

employee:
  name:
    employee1

headers:
```

I have the dict_data as below:-

```
dict_data = {'Key1': 'value1', 'Key2': 'value2}
```

Now we have to append this dict to headers attribute in yaml.

And the yaml should look like below:-

```
---
version: 1.0

employee:
  name:
    employee1

headers:
  Key1: value1
  Key2: value2
```

I tried doing this with PyYaml using update keyword and dumped only the dict in yaml file and removed all other contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can read, update and rewrite as,

```
with open('filename.yaml','r') as yamlfile:
    current_yaml = yaml.safe_load(yamlfile) 
    current_yaml['headers'].update(dict_data)

if current_yaml:
    with open('filename.yaml','w') as yamlfile:
        yaml.safe_dump(current_yaml, yamlfile)
```