# How to Add data into an existing YAML script using PyYAML?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I want to add data inside the 'tags' key in this YAML script

```
# Generated by Chef, local modifications will be overwritten
---
env: nonprod
api_key: 5d9k8h43124g40j9ocmnb619h762d458
hostname: ''
bind_host: localhost
additional_endpoints: {}
tags:
- application_name:testin123
- cloud_supportteam:eagles
- technical_applicationid:0000
- application:default
- lifecycle:default
- function:default-api-key
dogstatsd_non_local_traffic: false
histogram_aggregates:
- max
- median
- avg
- count
```

which should be like this,

```
tags:
- application_name:testing123
- cloud_supportteam:eagles
- technical_applicationid:0000
- application:default
- lifecycle:default
- function:default-api-key
- managed_by:Teams
```

so far I have created this script that will append the data at the end of the file seems not the solution,

```
import yaml

data = {
    'tags': {
        '- managed_by': 'Teams'
    }
}

with open('test.yml', 'a') as outfile:
       yaml.dump(data, outfile,indent=2)
```

Comment: Read YAML file (using `yaml.load()`), change the resulted collection in a way you want, and then write that collection back to the file (using `yaml.dump()`). There are plenty questions on that topic on Stack Overflow. E.g. see [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68176819/how-to-append-data-to-existing-yaml).

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev Thank you for responding. I have gone through plenty of questions and couldn't find a suitable solution regarding this. I tried your example also. logically it's correct but not working in this regard. :) I need help figuring it out. Thank you!

Comment: "I tried your example also. logically it's correct but not working in this regard." - The approach with read-modify-write should work for your case. Probably, there is something wrong in your implementation of that approach. But we cannot help you in fixing that implementation since you didn't show it. Please, add to the question post your **fair** attempt: the code, its output, and describe why that output don't fit for your task.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out it like this and this is working,

```
import yaml
from yaml.loader import SafeLoader

with open('test.yaml', 'r') as f:
    data = dict(yaml.load(f,Loader=SafeLoader))
    data ['tags'].append('managed_by:teams')
    print(data['tags'])
with open ('test.yaml', 'w') as write:
    data2 = yaml.dump(data,write,sort_keys= False, default_flow_style=False)
```

and the output was like this,

```
['application_name:testin123', 'cloud_supportteam:eagles', 'technical_applicationid:0000', 'application:default', 'lifecycle:default', 'function:default-api-key', 'managed_by:teams']
```

and the test.yaml file was updated,

```
tags:
- application_name:testing123
- cloud_supportteam:eagles
- technical_applicationid:0000
- application:default
- lifecycle:default
- function:default-api-key
- managed_by:teams
```